# discord.errors.ClientException: C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg was not found

Tags: ffmpeg, discord.py

I'm trying to create a music bot for my discord. All I want right now is for my discord bot to play a music clip. I've found no solutions at all.

```
@commands.command()
async def play(self, ctx, url):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    channel = await channel.connect()
    guild = ctx.guild
    voice_client: discord.VoiceClient = discord.utils.get(self.bot.voice_clients, guild=guild)
    audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable="C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg", source="alex_sus.mp3")
    if not voice_client.is_playing():
        voice_client.play(audio_source, after=None)
```

This is exactly my code but I get the error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg was not found.
```

The file is most definitely in the location I specified and I put ffmpeg into my env path. I've followed every instruction when installing ffmpeg, but nothing I do works. I just want to note that ffmpeg is on my C drive, while the code is on my D drive. Idk if this makes a difference or not.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you need to add the file extension. Your windows file explorer probably hides the extension by default.

```py
executable="C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe"
```